# Why does docker run do nothing when i try to run my app?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I made a website to React and I'm trying to deploy it to an Nginx server by using Docker. My Dockerfile is in the root folder of my project and looks like this:

```
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN yarn run build


# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend
COPY --from=build-stage /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

When I run `docker build -t mywebsite .` on the docker terminal I receive a small warning that I'm building a docker image from windows against a non-windows Docker host but that doesn't seem to be a problem.

However, when I run `docker run mywebsite` nothing happens, at all.

In case it's necessary, my project website is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/rgomez96/Tecnolab

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting ? Nothing will happen on the console except the nginx log.
You should see something happening if you go to *http:ip_of_your_container*.

Otherwise, you can just launch your container with this command :
`docker container run -d -p 80:80 mywebsite`
With this command you'll be able to connect to your nginx at this address **http://localhost** as you are forwarding all traffic from the port 80 of your container to the port 80 of your host.